# Cannot Import SHAP in jupyter notebook. showing system error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, shap, system-error

### After instaling SHAP using
!pip install shap
import shap
the error shows:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import shap

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\shap_*init*_.py in 
10     warnings.warn("As of version 0.29.0 shap only supports Python 3 (not 2)!")
11
---> 12 from ._explanation import Explanation, Cohorts
13
14 # explainers

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\shap_explanation.py in 
10 from slicer import Slicer, Alias, Obj
11 # from ._order import Order
---> 12 from .utils._general import OpChain
13 from .utils._exceptions import DimensionError
14

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\shap\utils_*init*_.py in 
----> 1 from ._clustering import hclust_ordering, partition_tree, partition_tree_shuffle, delta_minimization_order, hclust
2 from ._general import approximate_interactions, potential_interactions, sample, safe_isinstance, assert_import, record_import_error
3 from ._general import shapley_coefficients, convert_name, format_value, ordinal_str, OpChain, suppress_stderr
4 from ._show_progress import show_progress
5 from ._masked_model import MaskedModel, make_masks

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\shap\utils_clustering.py in 
2 import scipy as sp
3 from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
----> 4 from numba import jit
5 import sklearn
6 import warnings

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba_*init*_.py in 
41
42 # Re-export vectorize decorators and the thread layer querying function
---> 43 from numba.np.ufunc import (vectorize, guvectorize, threading_layer,
44                             get_num_threads, set_num_threads)
45

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc_*init*_.py in 
1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
2
----> 3 from numba.np.ufunc.decorators import Vectorize, GUVectorize, vectorize, guvectorize
4 from numba.np.ufunc._internal import PyUFunc_None, PyUFunc_Zero, PyUFunc_One
5 from numba.np.ufunc import _internal, array_exprs

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\decorators.py in 
1 import inspect
2
----> 3 from numba.np.ufunc import _internal
4 from numba.np.ufunc.parallel import ParallelUFuncBuilder, ParallelGUFuncBuilder
5

SystemError: initialization of _internal failed without raising an exception

i tried updating my python environment, it did not work.

Comment: What the error says is that you are running Python 2, and `shap` only supports Python 3.  If you are running Python 2, it's long past time to upgrade.